# Trouble understanding inductive proof of Lomuto's partitioning algorithm

Tags: sorting, correctness-proof, induction

I'm doing a review of sorting algorithms and trying to self-learn how to prove them as well. The foundation of the quicksort proof is intuitive enough if I'm assuming that the recursion holds - but you also need to assume that the partitioning algorithm works as well.

I'm having trouble approaching an inductive proof for Lomuto's partition; I'm particularly not understanding what would be a good loop invariant to start with here. When I was going about doing a similar proof for mergesort, the invariant for merge was a bit more intuitive as it was based on an assumption that for all iterations k, the element I would copy into my final array at position k would be the minimum of all available elements. I'm not understanding how to do a similar thing with Lomuto, or if I'm looking in the right direction.

Comment: Look for parts of the data that are done with, what is true about these parts and needs to be shown to remain true in each trip.